# Automatically to remove row from table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two entities:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
}

public class Chapter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Period { get; set; }
}
```

and, i want that entityframework automatically was be do removed row from table Chapter where foreign key (Book_Id) is null. Please help, how i can do it ?

Comment: What do your mappings look like for you entities?

Comment: i want, that where was remove Chapter from collection Chapters  of Book entity, automatically was been remove row from table in Database.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your mappings, I would suggest adding a navigation property from `Chapter` back To `Book`. In your mapping for Chapter make sure to set the `WillCascadeOnDelete`. This will ensure if a `Book` is removed, all `Chapters` will be deleted as well.

```
public class Book
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
    }

    public class Chapter
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual int BookId {get;set;}
        public virtual Book Book {get;set;}
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Period { get; set; }
    }

     public class ChapterMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Chapter>
        {
            public ChapterMapping
            {
                HasKey(c=> c.Id);
                Property(c => c.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(
                    DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
                HasRequired(c => c.Book).WithMany(b => b.Chapters)
               .HasForeignKey(c => c.BookId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

            }

        }
```

Comment: i need to remove row from table where Chapter will be removed from collection of Book, but not was been removed Book entity

Comment: Are you allowing Chapters without a Book entity? I am not sure what you are trying to do.